# Launch Windows Start menu programmatically

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java application, and I need to open up the Windows Start menu programmatically.

I searched cmd commands for this but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Reformulated the question slightly. Hopefully it's no longer _"unclear what you're asking"_. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to use the `Robot` class to emulate a keypress on the Win-key.

Comment: Didn't know that class, awesome!

Comment: Start menu pops up on key release. So make sure you release the Win key by using `keyRelease` after `keyPress`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is through the Windows shell.

Try doing this:

```
set wShell=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
 wShell.sendkeys "^{ESC}"
 Set WshShell = Nothing
```

By using the method outlined here -> http://www.javaquery.com/2011/02/how-to-execute-microsft-windowss-shell.html